# MySQL: Get index of a specific row

Tags: sql, indexing, row

I want to get the index of a specific row that is determined by a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT * FROM bidrag WHERE bidrag_id = $bidrag_id
```

How can i get the index of this row in the table?

Comment: What do you mean by index?. The position in which it is stored?. If you have an auto-increment column you can use that value.

Comment: Has your table some kind of row number?

Comment: Are you referring to the ordinal position?